# How to make a join only on selected values of a column on another table in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Hello I have a main table **table1** that has *n* columns with a column name called **R_Id** this column is a primary key (Id) in another table **table2**. I want to make a join such that I want to retain all the values and columns of **table1** but filter the **table1** where the R_Id is 13, 3 and 4.

Simply, I can try this i.e.

```
select * from table1 
where table1.R_Id in (13, 3, 4)
```

but this will filter the whole **table1** based on these three values. I want to retain the table1 and all its value and filter only this particular column. I tried something like this but it doesn't work

```
select * from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.R_Id = t2.Id
where t1.R_Id in (13, 3, 4)
```

But this unfortunately doesn't work.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You must set the condition in the `ON` clause, so that all rows of table1 are returned but only the rows with `t1.R_Id IN (13, 3, 4)` are joined to `table2`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 
ON t1.R_Id = t2.Id AND t1.R_Id IN (13, 3, 4)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply that works but what if I want to also remove all the rows from table1 where the R_Id is not in 13, 3, 4

Comment: @MurtazaBasu this is what the WHERE clause does and you say in your question that you don't want it.

Comment: what I want is to keep the table1 and all its rows but remove only those rows where the value of R_Id is not 13, 3, 4

Comment: @MurtazaBasu so you don't want all the rows of table1. You want only the rows with R_Id equal to 13 or 3 or 4. Then why `where table1.R_Id in (13, 3, 4)` does not work?

Comment: because it removes all the other rows in table1, and returns only those rows where table1.R_Id is 13, 3 or 4

Comment: Unless there are nulls in the column R_Id then *remove only those rows where the value of R_Id is not 13, 3, 4* means *return only those rows where table.R_Id is 13, 3 or 4*. So  your requirement is not clear. Post sample data and expected results to clarify.